# webos com.palm.pdf service question

Tags: pdf, webos

I'm trying to reproduce standard PDF viewer. I've copied sources but after they are deployed to the emulator the following error appears in log
when user hits 'next'/'prev' page in it:
Error: service request: palm://com.palm.pdf is not running

This is happened in the following code:

```
executeJump: function ( numPages ) {
    Mojo.Log.info("JUMPING TO THE PAGE: " + numPages);
    //this.controller.serviceRequest('palm://com.palm.pdf/events', {
    this.controller.serviceRequest('palm://com.palm.pdf/events', {
        method: 'jumpToPage',
        parameters: {
            docid: this.document_id,
            numPages: numPages
        },
        onSuccess: function(payload) {
            if ((payload.errorCode !== undefined) || (payload.curPage === undefined)) {
                Mojo.Log.error("executeJump failed: " + Object.toJSON( payload ) );
                return;
            }

            this.currentpage = payload.curPage;

        }.bind(this)
    });

},
```

I've googled though the all services but I can't find any documentation of this one (com.palm.pdf)
Why it is not started in my app but starts in the standard one? The standard app is called com.palm.pdfviewer.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution: http://blog.shevchuk.org/2009/08/18/webos-palm-pdf-service-error/